# Is there a way to force an element to be sticky on mobile as opposed to entering only once you scroll up a bit?

Tags: html, css

I have a table that I want the header row to be sticky. Which works exactly as expected on desktop. As soon as you scroll past the element it just sticks right to the top of the page.

Sticky point not reached:
[image]

Sticky point reached:
[image]

I'm simply using `position: sticky` to accomplish this.

On mobile however it does not immediately stick, if you scroll down the header row is not sticky, as you start to scroll back up the stick header will appear. Only once you start to scroll down does it disappear again.

Here is a video demonstrating what I mean: https://i.imgur.com/8rYHMbR.mp4

You'll see that as you scroll up a bit eventually the sticky header does pop in to view.

Is there a CSS parameter to force a header on mobile to stick *always* as opposed to on scroll movements?

I know this could be accomplished with JavaScript which I'll fall back to if need be but I wanted to see if there is a parameter I'm missing.

Below is the CSS I have currently:

```
table{
  border-spacing: 0;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
}

table, th{
  background: #c0c7c8;
}

tbody td{
  text-align: center;
}

th{
  padding: 12px !important;
}

td, th{
  border-top: 2px solid #e3e6e6;
  border-right: 1px solid #e3e6e6;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e6e6;
  border-left: 2px solid #e3e6e6;
  padding: 8px;
}

.stick_providers{
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  top: 0;
}
```

With the `.sticky providers` class being applied to tables that need it like so...

```
<table class="provider_list">
    <thead class="stick_providers">
      <tr>
        <th v-for="(status,provider) in providers_list" :class="toProvideOrNotProvide(provider)">{{provider}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="channel in channel_lineups" :class="toShowOrNotToShow(channel.Provider)">
        <td v-for="(status, provider) in channel" :class="yesNoHighlighter(status,provider)">
          {{status}}
          <span class="mobile-helper-channel-id">{{channel.Provider}}</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My guess is that there is something under pinning the rendering engine of Chrome and Firefox (and I assume Safari as well) which makes "sticky" elements behave to only become sticky when people scroll back towards them or might need them. Similar to how their address/toolbars work within the browsers on mobile.

If there is any way around this I'd love to know.

Comment: I notice that both times in the video, when scrolling up, it begins to show around the `MTV` section. Does it show around that section?

Comment: That is an interesting point. I just did some more testing and it appears to be largely coincidence. You can get it to appear at other times. It does pop in most often around that point but my guess is that is because there is some underlying code based on the overall height of the table or distance scrolled which causes the browser to trigger bringing the sticky element back into view.

Answer (score 0):

```css
table,
    th,
    td {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 30px;
        border: solid 1px red;
    }

    th {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        background-color: white;
    }
```

```html
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Hello</th>
                <th>World</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>HTML</td>
            <td>CSS</td>
        </tr>


    </table>
```